# Android screen mirror to android with usb c to c cable

Tags: android-emulator, motorola, screen-mirroring

Can I mirror a note 10 screen to a Moto Z4 with a projection mod to project the Note 10 to my wall? The purpose is to play more powerful emulator games on the Note and use the Moto w/ projection mod just like a projector. I plan on doing this with a usb c to c cable. Is that even possible or are there alternatives?

Comment: An device-to-device connection via USB may be possible via `adb` using one device as regular adb client and the other running `adb server` in termux. Based on the adb connection screen casting may be possible but this scenario is not very common. However keep in mind that such a connection with screen casting will increase latency, as you want to run games this may be a problem depending on the resulting latency.